# How to get Runtime Library and Build Type from the obj file?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I work on Windows 10. I use cmake with Visual Studio 15 2017 generator. Do you know any tool which allow to check Runtime Library and Build Type based on the obj file ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/), it might work.